# azure-devops-extension-sdk: Configuration of widget

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I try to create a widget for monitor builds in pipeline using new [azure-devops-extension-sdk](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/develop/extensions) but I can't find information about how to add custom fields to configuration page. Can anyone share information or example for it?

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that you use the [old SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops#part-3-hello-world-with-configuration) to develop widgets. [The good news](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk/issues/17#issuecomment-530582870) is that they are investigating adding support for developing them using the new SDK. In addition, here is a [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk/issues/17#issuecomment-599713666) and you can refer to it. You can also vote and follow this ticket about [target Date for Widget support](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk/issues/22).

Comment: I found the sample but I don't undestand how to use it. And MS sample repo doesn't contain any examples about widgets. We can't use the old SDK because develop was started with using the new SDK.